# Shuffling an Array (Java)

Tags: java, shuffle

I’m trying to randomly shuffle integers in an array. That seems simple enough, but I have to shuffle them so that they still remain in a particular order (odd, even, odd, even, etc). For example, if the original array contained [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] then the shuffled array might look like [5, 8, 7, 4, 1, 6, 3, 2], but always retaining the same alternating order, starting with odd.

Thanks for the help. 
By the way, this isn’t my exact homework problem. I just want to figure out how to do this so that I can do my homework. I don’t know where to start.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably:

1. Grab all the elements at the ODD indexed positions into a separate
   array and shuffle that
2. Grab all the elements at the EVEN indexed positions into a separate array and shuffle that; then
3. Splice them back to together

Comment: If I were to splice both of those arrays back together, wouldn't that make all the odds on one side and all the evens on the other?

Comment: "splice" here refers to an operation where, from two arrays, `[a,b,c]` and `[x,y,z]`, you create a new one, `[a,x,b,y,c,z]` - basically "interweaving" the elements of the two arrays, alternatingly.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks for clarifying. How would I achieve this? Sorry for the confusion, I'm still a little new to this.

Comment: Assuming two arrays `odds` and `evens` containing the shuffled individual arrays and `spliced` the new array to hold the result then in pseduocode something along the lines of:
`for i in len(odds): spliced.push(odds[i]); spliced.push(evens[i]); next i`

Comment: You'll have to be careful with final value of `i` since, depending on the length of the original array the length of `evens` may be 1 shorter than the length of `odds`.

Answer (score 1):

You can let the desired elements of the array *appear* as a `List<Integer>`, by implementing `AbstractList` accordingly, as a *view* on the relevant array elements. Then, a simple `Collections#shuffle` on the lists will do the trick.

This may seem "unconventional" at the first glance, but has some advantages:

- it operates on `int` arrays (although you can change it to `Integer` if you want to)
- it does not need to copy the array (no additional memory overhead)
- it does not need to "process" the array in any way (other than shuffling it)

Implemented here as an MCVE:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ConstrainedShuffle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        int array[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(array));

        constrainedShuffle(array, new Random(0));

        System.out.println("After : " + Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    private static void constrainedShuffle(int array[], Random random)
    {
        Collections.shuffle(asList(array, 0, 2), random);
        Collections.shuffle(asList(array, 1, 2), random);
    }

    private static List<Integer> asList(int array[], int offset, int stride)
    {
        int size = (array.length - offset + stride - 1) / stride;
        return new AbstractList<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public Integer get(int index)
            {
                return array[offset + index * stride];
            }

            @Override
            public Integer set(int index, Integer element)
            {
                int i = offset + index * stride;
                Integer old = array[i];
                array[i] = element;
                return old;
            }

            @Override
            public int size()
            {
                return size;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to shuffle your array would be to "randomly sort" the items.

For example if you are using Java 8 or above, you could provide a sorting compartor as a lambda shown below, that simply returns positive or negative indices at each iteration during the sorting operation to obtain a shuffled result:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Random random = new Random();

/* Ordered input list */
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);

/* Apply random sorting behavior to achieve obtain a shuffled array */
Collections.sort(list, (Integer a, Integer b) -> {
    /* Obtain random number between 0 - 1 */
    Integer randomValue = random.nextInt(1);

    /* Return random positive or negative value which causes "shuffled" 
    sort */
    return randomValue == 1 ? 1 : -1;
});

/* list is now shuffled */
```

Comment: You have a ArrayList<Integer[]> and you add Integers to it? Java generics are bad, but I had no idea that they considered integer arrays and integers the same thing!

Comment: The point of the question was not to shuffle the array, but to shuffle it in a way that retains the odd-even order of the elements. Apart from that, why should you implement something like `Collections#shuffle` (which is O(n)) based on `Collections.sort` (which is O(nlogn))?

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
```

With array as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
I get output `[9, 5, 8, 2, 0, 7, 4, 3, 6, 1]`

Let it be noted that it cannot work with primitive arrays, `int[]` will not work only `Integer[]`

Comment: The point of the question was not to shuffle the array, but to shuffle it in a way that retains the odd-even order of the elements.